# Is it possible to host an NPM registry on static file server?

Tags: npm, hosting, static-files

I want to host an npm registry, and i'd love this to be a bunch of static files in Azure blob storage or Amazon S3.

Is that possible for npm packages?

Comment: I'm also very interested by this question. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @GromNaN nope...